# Alamofire Slows down on big JSON responses

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

When I request a URL which brings back a big JSON response PostMan takes only 500 ms to respond. but with Alamofire 4.4 it takes like 3 seconds. I noticed that the transfer-encoding in Postman is chunked but with Alamofire is Identity.
any solutions?

Comment: My problem too please post an answer if you found something

Comment: Anybody found a solution for this problem yet??